# I am trying to make a Twitter bot using Tweepy and Python, but I get Error 215?

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am trying to create a Twitter bot that follows the people that follow me. However I am getting Error 215: Bad Authentication data. Im pretty sure it is twitter not authorizing my credentials, but i am not sure, and i dont know how to fix it.

here is my config file:

```
import tweepy
import logging
import os

logger=logging.getLogger()

def create_api():
    consumer_key= os.getenv("CONSUMER_KEY")
    consumer_secret= os.getenv("CONSUMER_SECRET")
    access_token= os.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN")
    access_token_secret= os.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")


    auth= tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api= tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    #api=tweepy.API(auth)


    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error in creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise e
    logger.info("API created")
    return api
```

here is my following follower file

```
import tweepy 
import logging
from config import create_api
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger=logging.getLogger()

def follow_followers(api):
    logger.info("Retrieving and following followers")
    for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers).items():
        if not follower.following:
            logger.info(f"Following {follower.name}")
            follower.follow()
def main():
    api= create_api()
    while True:
        follow_followers(api)
        logger.info("Waiting...")
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I then use my windows terminal to set CONSUMER_KEY="XXX" etc and i het a tweep.error.TweepError [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]

any suggestions to fix?

Comment: It might be a typo in your question here, but do you have any spaces in your keys and tokens on either side of the `=` character when you set them in the Windows environment?

Comment: Sorry , yes, thats a typo. when I set my keys and token i use set CONSUMER_KEY="XXX" ..I'm assuming that is correct?

Comment: It looks like it should be ok, you might try having your `create_api` method print out the values it got from the environment to be sure everything is being passed in correctly.

Comment: okay so I ran a test and it seems that my credentials are not being authenticated. I used api.verify_credentials and it does not verify...any idea what the problem is?

Comment: UPDATE: it works now, but i had to use credentials from an old app. Also had to hard code my credentials (obviously not ideal for safety reasons ..) So it seams that inputting my credentials into my terminal doesnt work...weird. Any suggestions to fix would be great as I dont wanna leave my code hard coded